# How can I Install Visual Studio 2015 vdproj extension without internet connection

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions, vdproj

I'm attempting to install the vdproj extension for Visual Studio 2015. The target machine has no internet connection. When initially installing Visual Studio it was possible to create an offline installer using the following,
`vs_enterprise.exe --layout c:\vslayout`

Is there a way to do the same thing with a VS extension?

Downloaded 5Mb VSI_bundle.exe (Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Installer Projects) from Visual Studio Marketplace however the installation failed due to no internet connection.

Comment: Command line options are slightly different.

`vsi_bundle.exe /Layout` worked.

Questions answered.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here. You can add it as answer and mark it after two days.